# how to allow moving li items in only one list?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a multiple ul and in each ul there are multiple li. Whenever some one clicks on the li item it gets selected and then there are up and down buttons which move the selected li items up and down. Below is jquery code of the buttons

```
    //onclick of move up button ,move the item up in the list
$("#btn-move-up").click(function () {
    $item = $(".highlight");
    $before = $item.first().prev();
    $item.insertBefore($before);
});

//onclick of move down button, move the item down in the list
$("#btn-move-down").click(function () {
    $item = $(".highlight");
    $after = $item.last().next();
    $item.insertAfter($after);
});
```

What I want is to allow li item moving in the corresponding list only. 
e.g. if there are two list

```
<ul id="1">
<li>item 1 </li>
<li>item 2 </li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="2">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

if some one clicks on item 2 of 1st list and item 3 of second list and then click move up button I only want them to move up in their respected list and do not want the li items to copied in the other list and then moved up as it is happening now.
Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: how are you determining the selected `li` ?

Comment: when some one clicks on the li I assigned a class called "highlight" to it and then I am getting all the items having this class in my button click.

Comment: Hoe do you distinguish the 'corresponding list' ?

Comment: yup, without seeing the full html and how you determine what is selected.  It's hard to guess.  your highlight class, you can try .closest('ul').attr('id') to get the container it belongs to.  hope it helps

Comment: can there be 2 highlights at the same time?

Comment: When you use `$(".highlight")` it selects all the highlighted items - just do a  `$(item).each(` so each one gets its own `prev`/`next`

Comment: @AnoopJoshi thats the problem , how can I distinguish the "corresponding list" ?

Comment: We need the complete html structure. Do you have different up, down buttons for different lists?

Comment: yes @chungtinhlakho there can be multiple highlights at the same time.

Comment: @freedomn-m already tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: where is #btn-move-down and #btn-move-up elements?

Comment: can you do an example of how exactly I should use each function?@freedomn-m

Comment: @BilalHussain Can you provide what you tried for the `$.each` version?  That should work.

Comment: $('.highlight').each(function(item){item is your highlight....})

Comment: see the answer and see if it works.  i think that might do it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down your code:

```
$item = $(".highlight");
```

gets all the highglighted items (assume `li`s only)

```
$before = $item.first().prev();
```

.first gets the first one and then the `li` above it

```
$item.insertBefore($before);
```

takes *all* the items and puts them at the before

Because `$item` is a collection/array of items (which is why you use .first) any actions apply to the whole array.

You could change the last line to:

```
$item.first().insertBefore($before);
```

but then only one will move up at a time.

Alternatively, work on one item at a time, eg:

```
$("#btn-move-up").click(function () {
    $items = $(".highlight");
    $items.each(function(index) {
        $before = $(this).prev();
        $(this).insertBefore($before);
    });
});
```

Comment: the 2nd solution is the one I need.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

based on what you tell us, give this a try

```
//onclick of move up button ,move the item up in the list
$("#btn-move-up").click(function () {
    $(".highlight").each(function()
    {
      $item = $(this);
      $before = $item.first().prev();
      $item.insertBefore($before);
   })
});

//onclick of move down button, move the item down in the list
$("#btn-move-down").click(function () {
    $(".highlight").each(function()
    {  
      $item = $(this);
      $after = $item.last().next();
      $item.insertAfter($after);
    })
});
```